# How to auto mount a secondary, internal HDD so a symbolic link to it will work from startup?

Tags: command-line, hard-drive, symbolic-link

My system has a dual storage configuration that consists of a PCIe SSD where the OS is located and a secondary, internal HDD for general mass storage needs.

I can easily mount the HDD via the GUI and I've created a symbolic link to it which works after I've mounted the HDD via the GUI. However, prior to taking the aforementioned step my symbolic link will not work.

Is there a way to remove the need to mount the HDD manually so my symbolic link always works?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. What is the link pointing to? How is the disk mounted? Are you sure you mean "spin up" and don't just need it to be mounted?

Comment: Eh symbolic links can span over disks? You should use `mount --bind` :P

Comment: @Rinzwind yes, symlinks span disks - I've folder on secondary HDD with all my virtualbox images there , and symlink to that is in my home folder.

Comment: @terdon The disk always appears mounted in Nautilus it's just not active. So the symbolic link I created appears red in Terminal.  So by 'spin up' I meant after clicking the drive it can hear it begin to spin. Apologies for any ambiguity.

Comment: @Rinzwind Could you maybe give a little more information as I'm not currently familiar with mount --bind? Thanks!

Comment: oh it is very simple: `mount --bind {dir} {dir2}` That would connect dir to dir2 ;)

Comment: @MACourtney7 unless the disk is mounted at boot via `/etc/fstab` it won't be active.  So I'm pretty sure what you're doing is mounting the disk when you click on it

Comment: @MACourtney7 the disk is shown nin nautilus yes, but that doesn't mean it is mounted. Depending on your setup, clicking on it in nautilus will mount it. So, please [edit] your question as I asked before and give us more details. We don't even know if this is an internal or an external drive. It could even just be another partition.

Comment: @terdon I've added more information, I hope this helps. I did say that it was a secondary HDD. Why does it matter whether it is internal or external? It shouldn't change how the OS utilises it.

Comment: Ah, but it does :) USB drives are usually handled by [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) and internal ones are (again usually) controlled through entries in `/etc/fstab`. So, you just need to set this disk to always mount on boot as described in Serg's answer. For more details, edit your question and show us your current `/etc/fstab` and the output of `lsblk`.

Comment: Right, I see. I forgot about udev. I hope the updated version of the question better explains things. I've noticed that the disk in question still has its ntfs formatting from the Windows preinstall so after I've reformatted later I will add to my fstab file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing via GUI is that you're mounting the filesystem. Once a filesystem is mounted, files can be accessed ( if the drive is mounted with appropriate permissions ).

There's a couple things you can do to make your life easier:

1. Mount the filesystem at boot via `/etc/fstab` file. Obtain the UUID of that partition via `sudo blkid` command. Write a line in `/etc/fstab`  that should look roughly like this:

   ```
   # The 400 GB partition on the native HDD
   UUID=8e344ab1-5eb5-4e20-becd-4147fffd439f /mnt/HDD ext4 noatime,nodiratime,rw
   ```

   The example above is my actual setup. As mentioned in comments , I've a symlink to folder on that 400 Gb partition. If hard drive is mounted at boot, the symlink always works (of course , you have to ensure that you mount filesystem at proper directory and symlink is pointing to right file/folder).
2. If you wish to mount the filesystem on-demand, use this command for mounting: `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdX` , where `/dev/sdX` is device file of that filesystem. This is essentially the same thing that GUI method uses. This can be scripted as well

Comment: Thanks for this. What have you included after the UUID and how should I translate it to what I need?

Comment: `/mnt/HDD` is actually the folder to which you mount the drive, ext4 is filesystem type ( ntfs for Window ), and `noatime,nodiratime,rw` are the options. First two minimize unnecessary reads,writes and rw grants read-write permissions to all users